# Facebook Client Certificate error

Tags: facebook, ssl

I'm working on a Facebook app and have invited some testers to join in.
It has been tested on PC (IE, Chrome, FF) and on my Macbook Pro Maverick (Safari) with no problems.

However, our client (who also uses a Macbook Pro, OS-version unknown) is greeted by the message below - but only in Safari. Our server runs a 2003 IIS with Wildcard SSL certificate. I and several others are unable to replicate the error - and I belive that it's a local problem, since it works in Firefox on his computer.

I've read about client certificates and they are apparently "an optional part"

Any suggestions regarding how to fix it or what I tell our client?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just searched on the internet and I've found same problem in other forum.

Open below link, and read the answer given, It can solve your question.

https://discussions.apple.com/message/18110175

Hope, It will helps to you.

Thanks!